# How do I check if a service method's parameter type is an output type given the parameter's ParameterInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, types, parameters

Given a certain [ParameterInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the parameter of a service method, I would like to check if this parameter is an output type. Would it be enough to check if its `ParameterType` contains an `&` sign at the end? I've noticed objects like `System.String` become `System.String&` when they are output types, or, is there a better way to check for this?

Comment: do you mean does the property use the `out` keyword? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.isout.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParameterInfo p = ...;

bool isOutParam = (p.Attributes & System.Reflection.ParameterAttributes.Out) == System.Reflection.ParameterAttributes.Out;

Comment: Alternatively: `bool isOutParam = p.IsOut;` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.isout.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect guys. Exactly what I wanted.